# Mysql query not return correct result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have two tables

one is user_matchs

```
id | user_id  | matched_user_id  |  status
36 |    17    |       24         |  passed
37 |    17    |       25         |  friend
```

another is users

```
id | name     | address |  age
17 |  mamun   | test    |   23
25 |  shihab  | test2   |   30
24 |  shihab2 | test22  |   30
```

Now I want to retrieve list of all users depending on some condition with given `userId`

suppose I am user 17. now I want to see all user  whose are not my friend and whose passed me.if user_matchs table

`user_id=17 and matched_user_id=24 and status=passed` then it means i passed user 24 but 24 not passed me if 24 also passed me then row will be

```
user_id=17 and matched_user_id=24 and status=friend
```

another logic

`user_id=24 and matched_user_id=17 and status=passed` then it means user 24 passed  me  but i am not passed user 17 if 17 also passed me then row will be

```
user_id=24 and matched_user_id=17 and and status=friend
```

When I give userId 17 with search query, it returns no user because user 25 is friend of user 17 and user 17 already passed user 24.

But when I give userId 24 in the search query, then it returns user 17 and 25. Because user 25 is not friend or have not passed user 24 and user 17 is not friend of or user 24 not passed user 17.

I am trying with this query but it does not work correctly:here 24 is given id

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE users.id != 24 AND

        users.id NOT IN (SELECT matched_user_id
                               FROM `user_matchs`
                               WHERE user_id = '24'
                              )
and
        users.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id
                               FROM `user_matchs`
                               WHERE matched_user_id = '24'
                              )
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbca2f/1)

Comment: What is the query supposed to do? What does "some condition with given `userId`" mean?

Comment: I update my question please take a look @Barmar

Comment: Your query never checks the `status` column, how is it supposed to tell if the user passed you?

Comment: how can i solve it now. can you give me any query logic @Barmar

Comment: Your sqlfiddle just returns 25. Why do you say it returns 17 and 25? Is that what you _want_ it to return?

Comment: If give userId 24 in the search query, then it returns user 17 and 25. Because user 25 is not friend or have not passed user 24 and user 17 is not friend of or user 24 not passed user 17. @Barmar

Comment: Repeating what you said in the question doesn't make it any clearer. Is 17 and 25 what it SHOULD return, or is it what it DOES return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second subquery needs to check the `status` field, so it only excludes friends, not people who have passed you.

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE users.id != 24 AND

    users.id NOT IN (SELECT matched_user_id
                        FROM `user_matchs`
                        WHERE user_id = '24'
                    )
and
    users.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id
                        FROM `user_matchs`
                        WHERE matched_user_id = '24'
                        AND status = 'friend'
                    )
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbca2f/5)